# How to extract text by unspecified spaces

Tags: bash

I'm trying to extract usernames from a text file in one per line format and from my research, it seems like the only way to do it is by spacing commands here's the format:

```
1   user    3 
2   fusrfff 4
3   usrf    12
```

The only problem is because all of the users are different I can't define a static space amount. There's also the fact the UIDs (first numbers) go from 1-40k. There's a bunch of other information after the user group number too. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Comment: I can't understand what you mean by "spacing commands" or "define a static space amount". This seems to be context-specific to your work, and you should explain something further in your question. Also, i can't figure what the real question is... Maybe you can edit?

Comment: Stack Overflow is about helping you fix a program you've started but can't quite get working. Not about doing all the work for you. Start writing a script. Debug it for a while. If you solve the problem, then you're done. If not, come back and only then ask, showing what you've done and where you've run into trouble.

Answer (score 2):

`awk` does not care about the amount of space between fields:

```
awk '{print $2}' your_file.txt
```

If you want to go with `bash` only, `read` does not care either:

```
while read uid username other_stuff; do
    printf '%s\n' "$name"
done < your_file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

First replace spaces by one space. You can use `sed 's/ +/ /g'` or

```
tr -s " " < file.txt| cut -d" " -f2
```

Answer (score 0):

This is using **sed**

```
$ cat file.txt| sed  "s/  */ /g" | cut -d' ' -f2
user
fusrfff
usrf
```